# Is there a way to know which port is been published from within a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have a python-gunicorn web server that runs on docker. I want to run multiple servers on the same machine so I assigned a "random" port to each container like this:

```
$ docker run -d -p 0:80 image
```

If I run `$ docker ps`, I can see the port been used by the container:

```
0.0.0.0:32771->80/tcp
```

Now, I want to retrieve this number (32771) from within the container. Is there anyway to do this?

Edit:
I want this information because I need to connect to these servers from another machine and the way it is implemented requires that the server sends its url via HTTP Post: IP:Port/path

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do that from within the container?

Comment: I want this information because I need to connect to these servers from another machine and the way it is implemented requires that the server sends its url via HTTP Post: IP:Port/path

Comment: If you want to connect to these servers from another machine, the internal port (`327771`) should be of no consequence.  The caller only needs to know about port `80`.

Comment: Hey, Jeff. Thanks for the help. I am sorry if it wasn't clear, but the port 80 is actually the internal port. The port 327771 is the mapped (external) port that I want to obtain.

Comment: "I am sorry if it wasn't clear, but the port 80 is actually the internal port." - Think I think port 80 should be of no consequence and the caller only needs to know about port `327771`.